# How to find out what part of a multi-statement mysql_query was matched using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have a query in PHP. It's much more complex, but for clarity let's say the query is:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE (foo = 'bar') OR (foo = 'bar_bar') OR (foo = 'bar_bar_bar')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

Is there a way to find out for each row of `$result` if it matched either `foo = 'bar'`, `foo = 'bar_bar'` or `foo = 'bar_bar_bar'`?

I know I could simply do this:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result) {
    switch($row['foo']) {
        case 'bar' :
        // we matched 'bar'
        break;
        case 'bar_bar' :
        // we matched 'bar_bar'
        break;
        case 'bar_bar_bar' :
        // we matched 'bar_bar_bar'
        break;
    }
}
```

But that's inefficient as you're basically querying your result, plus many queries and results would be way too complex to do it this way.

So, is there an easy and efficient way to find, for example an index of what statement of the query was matched, or is my best bet to split up the query in to separate queries?

Thanks.

Comment: This looks like an XY problem. Instead of fictional scenario, I'd include what you're really trying to solve (with the query and checking which condition was met and why do you have the need to know it in the first place).

Comment: Have you considered adding some columns like `$query = "SELECT my_table.*,IF(foo='bar',1,0),IF(foo='bar_bar',1,0),IF(foo='bar_bar_bar',1,0) FROM my_table`, and then you just check for `1` or `0` in your extra columns of your resultset.

Comment: @AntonioRagagnin that looks like the way to go, let me give it a shot.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you have to check that ? You can directly write the required function based on the result . 
In the function you are gonna write instead of hard coding it to a name just give

`$row['var_name']` .

Comment: As said, the actual query is too complex. It's somewhat like `$query = "SELECT entry_id FROM exp_channel_data WHERE channel_id = 7 AND (width = 5 AND diameter = 18 AND max_offset = 32 AND min_offset = 22 AND bolts = 4 AND pcd = 112) OR (width = 5 AND diameter = 19 AND max_offset = 31 AND min_offset = 22 AND bolts = 4 AND pcd = 125) OR (width = 5.25 AND diameter = 22 AND max_offset = 45 AND min_offset = 226 AND bolts = 4 AND pcd = 100)";` but then with about 20 statements. Then, depending on which one was matched, I need to do different stuff.

Answer (score 0):

you have to just select foo from my table

```
$query = "SELECT foo FROM my_table WHERE (foo = 'bar') OR (foo = 'bar_bar') OR (foo = 'bar_bar_bar')";
$result = mysql_query($query);
```

//You can simply use mysql_fetch_array() instead of mysql_fetch_assoc

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result) {
    switch($row['foo']) {
        case 'bar' :
        // we matched 'bar'
        break;
        case 'bar_bar' :
        // we matched 'bar_bar'
        break;
        case 'bar_bar_bar' :
        // we matched 'bar_bar_bar'
        break;
    }
}
```